# 100% height content <div> with sticky footer

Tags: css, height, sticky-footer

I need to have a fixed height header, a fixed height footer, and a 100% height div sandwiched in between (it's holding a full page background image). I'm using a sticky footer, as this is a template that will also be used for pages with regular content that might overflow (without the background image). This works on the regular pages, but on the page that requires a 100% height container, it fails. I can't get the 100% height div to expand to 100%. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the test page showing the problem I'm having with the 100% height div: http://www.dunnandtigheinteriors.com/new/wp-content/themes/dunntighe/testhome.html

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
/*    height: 100%;
    position: relative;  Required to absolutely position the footer 
    text-align: center;*/
}
#headerHolder {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 50px;
}
#bkgHolder {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    background: #DEDFE1;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-image: url('images/DunnTigheWhiteOverlay.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: auto 100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px; /* must be same height as the footer */
}
#footerHolder {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    color: #888888;
    background-color: #0074a2;
/*    position: absolute;*/
/*    bottom: 0;  Sit it on the bottom 
    left: 0;*/
    width: 100%; /* As wide as it's allowed */
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -25px;
    clear:both;
}
#footerHolder p {
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#pageText {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px; /* must be same height as the footer */
}
.pageContent {
    text-align: left;
    width: 680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

and html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='wrapper'>
            <div id="headerHolder">
            </div>
            <div id="bkgHolder">
                <div id='content'>
                    some content here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footerHolder">
                <p>All Content and Images, Copyright &copy;  Dunn & Tighe Interiors</p>
            </div>
    </body> </html>
```

Comment: Mind if I rewrite your template? I have a much easier solution.

Comment: If I add height: 100% onto the wrapper, it fixes the problem with the 100% height page, but then causes the pages that overflow to break (the sticky footer doesn't move to the bottom).

Comment: I understand. I'm making a template real quick for full content and lack thereof :-). One moment please.

Comment: Sorry its taking so long, getting your BG image to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this work?**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/8aLg3/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bkgHolder"></div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>I'm the Sticky Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='content'>
        <p>Some content here</p>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
    background:#CCC;
    height:50px;
}
#bkgHolder {
    background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top; 
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-10;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -25px; 
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.footer, .wrapper:after {
  height: 25px; 
}
.footer {
  background:#6AF;
}
p {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

### EDIT:

You could always do something like this?

#### JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/8aLg3/6/

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to find a solution, Nicholas. You don't know how much I appreciate it. It works great, except that the background image can't be cropped at all - it needs to be visible 100% height. Maybe by adding margins to #bkgHolder I can offset the header and footer?

Comment: Oh, I purposely added a `cover` to make it stretch. Yes, you could certainly crop it with **JS** in and `offset` to make it fit, but why not try your original code? One second.

Comment: [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/8aLg3/3/) I just simply used your code. I'm using a huge BG image. Just expand the bottom right window to the left and you'll see what I mean. If you want it further than this, are you trying to warp and stretch your background? :-/ The above code forces it 100% height but maintains aspect ratio. Oh, and I modified it from `cover` to `contain`.

Comment: @ibholland see above. If you CANNOT CROP NO MATTER WHAT, you WILL be breaking your aspect ratio. Is that acceptable? It will warp your images... [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/8aLg3/4/)

Comment: I wish, Nicholas, but the designer won't accept any warping or cropping. I've got to maintain the aspect ratio without cropping.

Answer (score 0):

### The last answer got convoluted. Let me identify what this does:

#### View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/8aLg3/9/

- Static Header that will be at the top of your page
- Static Footer that will remain on the bottom of your page
- Implemented a `jQuery` function that will size and resize on window resizing your image to the current restrains without breaking aspect ratio.
- BG Image will be inherently centered.

**A `javscript` solution to this is not ideal, but is required for what you're asking to accomplish.**

---

#### HTML:

```
<div id="bkgHolder"></div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>I'm the Sticky Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='content'>
        <p>Some content here</p>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

#### CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
    background:#CCC;
    height:50px;
}
#bkgHolder {
    background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size:contain;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:50px;
    z-index:-10;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -25px; 
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.footer, .wrapper:after {
  height: 25px; 
}
.footer {
  background:#6AF;
}
p {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

#### jQuery Script Addition:

```
$(function() {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    $('#bkgHolder').css({
        'width': w,
        'max-height': h-75,
    });
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        h = $(window).height();
        w = $(window).width();
        $('#bkgHolder').css({
            'width': w,
            'max-height': h-75,
        });
    } 
});
```

#### View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/8aLg3/9/

Comment: Here's an alternate solution for you that seems to work pretty well.